# delete[] pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, new-operator

I am using the new operator to create a dynamically allocated array (I am using this one because I want to save on the memory overhead of using a vector). The error occurs in the destructor, saying the pointer being freed was not allocated although obviously it was. The constructors and destructors are as follows:

```
~Path() {
    printf("Path Destructor\n");
    if(points) {
        delete[] points;
    }
}
Path(const std::vector<PathPoint>& points_) {
    size = points_.size();
    points = new PathPoint[size];
    int i = 0;
    for(const PathPoint& p : points_) {
        points[i++] = p;
    }
    printf("Path created\n");
}
```

Comment: What was `points_.size()`? Are there other constructors?

Comment: What memory overhead of a vector?

Comment: Did you define a copy constructor and or a copy assignment operator ?

Comment: @Niall It differs, size is from 1-5 usually. It crashes for 2 in my case, but I don't think it matters. There is no default constructor.

Comment: @quantdev No, is that necessary?

Comment: Think about it : what happens if a `Path` is copy constructed (or copy assigned) and then destructed ?

Comment: Yes, the copy and assignment would matter here. Read up on the "rule of three", or with C++11 the "rule of zero (or five)" (RAII).

Comment: @Gerard Why not simply use a `std::vector<PathPoint>` as your class member `points`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "Memory overhead" its in the question (see my comment).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I thought the overhead of a vector was 24 bytes, atleast that is what I get when I use sizeof(someVector). I thought this was a bit much for a vector that usually only contains 1-5 elements, and I have > 1 million of paths.

Comment: @Gerard You probably have a misconception what `sizeof(someVector)` actually does. It's the plain size of the `std::vector` class itself, not for the contained elements.

Comment: Do you `delete[] points` at any other location in the code? Or do you perhaps copy the `points` pointer and then `delete[]` the copy; maybe by copying the whole `Path` object (as others have hinted), or maybe by returning it through some public function to someone who later `delete`s it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes I know, so that is the overhead of using the vector right? It's some of its internal memory used (I imagine such as a size_t for keeping track of the size etc.)

Comment: Gerard's right πάνταῥεῖ.  For example, VC++2005 `vector` keeps 3 pointers (begin, end, capacity-extends-to), while it sounds like Gerard only need begin and a `uint8_t` size.  @Gerard - what's the size of `PathPoint`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to apply [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) :

The C++ standard says that :

> The implicitly-defined copy constructor for a non-union class X
>   performs a memberwise copy of its subobjects. [n3126.pdf section 12.8
>   §16]
>
> The implicitly-defined copy assignment operator for a non-union class
>   X performs memberwise copy assignment of its subobjects. [n3126.pdf
>   section 12.8 §30]

So the implicitly-defined copy constructor and copy assignment operator for your `Path` class will not call `new[]` for you.

Define a copy constructor and a copy assignment oerator that perform the required allocation.

---

**Note:**

- You can also make your type non copyable, declare them without definition :

E.g. :

```
 Path( const Path& other );      // non construction-copyable
 Path& operator=( const Path& ); // non copyable
```

(or use [`boost::noncopyable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/noncopyable.hpp))

- The typical overhead of a `std::vector<>` is very very low, there are few contexts where it really matters : use it as much as you can to avoid such problems.

Comment: Either that or *hide* the copy constructor/assignment operator, find out where the code is making copies of your millions of `Path`s, and stop it from doing that.

Comment: @dlf : yep, note added

Comment: @dlf, That is good advice, it seems somewhere    `paths.push_back(Path(points));` was calling the copy constructor and not allocating the memory like quantdev said. Thank you both.

Comment: @Gerard Yes, that will do it. You can use `paths.emplace_back(points)` to avoid the copy. You may also want to add a move constructor to `Path` to handle other scenarios.

Comment: By the way, I have always used vectors before but I think in this case the overhead reduction would be worth it, seeing that sizeof(vector) is 24 bytes, mine would be 2 + sizeof(PathPoint) * size. Or am I missing something?. Also my paths are relatively small <5, but the number of paths is huge so the small overhead is multiplied a great deal.

Comment: @dlf Ah right, well its good to adhere to this rule of three nevertheless :). Thanks

Comment: @Gerard Yes, if you're really dealing with millions of the things it's possible that it's worth the extra effort to avoid that otherwise-negligible 24-byte overhead. But if you're really bumping  into memory limits, you could do even better; e.g. by putting all the points for all the paths into one giant vector and keeping a separate vector the gives the starting index for each one.